# NavigationBar is hidden when push to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout, uinavigationbar

I have two viewcontrollers. The first viewcontroller is collection view controller and i set `self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true` in `viewDidLoad()`.

When I push the second `viewController` from the visible cell of collectionView, the navigation bar is showing in the second `viewController` but if I scroll the collectionView cell and when push the navigation is not showing.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: second view controller is also a CollectionView Controller ?

Comment: It's just normal viewcontroller.

Comment: bz are you used `hidesBarsOnSwipe` so if you scroll it will hidden

Answer (score 3):

scrolling is done via swipe gesture, so it triggers your code:

```
self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

because navigation controller is shared between all view controllers presented on top of it, it's properties (like hidden bar) preserves pushing / popping.

Common pattern is to change it's state in overrided lifecycle methods, eg:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

and reverting those state in `viewWillDisappear`

Answer (score 1):

When this property is set to true, an upward swipe hides the navigation bar and toolbar. A downward swipe shows both bars again. If the toolbar does not have any items, it remains visible even after a swipe. The default value of this property is false. (get it from apple)

See the doc https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621883-hidesbarsonswipe

It means when you swipe up it will hide and when swipe down it will shown. That's the reason.

To fix it you can add following code to the other controller

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't get much insight what exactly you implemented, but try to unhide navigation bar in second view controller.

Add below code in viewDidLoad method of second View controller.

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this `self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false` and this `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)` in your second view controller.

You might want to move your `self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true` from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear` in your first view controller.